# How do add Ad Mob to PhoneGap Build apps?

Tags: admob, phonegap-build

My PhoneGap Build apps are built in HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery Mobile.

The Ad Sense rule say that ads can only be added to mobile sites so I have to use Ad Mob.

But I can't find out how to add them to apps built with HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery Mobile.

Anyone know how?

Comment: There isn't one, yet, AFAIK. It's being worked on though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no plugin available. Keep your eye on https://build.phonegap.com/plugins for it to be added though. I am hoping someone will create/post one this month... I was hopeful for last month also though...

Comment: is it out now ? Can you please link me to the page ?

Comment: Looks like it isn't going to happen any time soon, if at all. Best option right now is to use the PhoneGap CLI. See the section titled "Build Applications Remotely" in the documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Answer (score 1):

there are several solutions on github.

1. https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob
2. https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

Comment: This is for PhoneGap. I'm using PhoneGap Build. Build is quite different.